# CSS Navbar items

Tags: css

Hello respected devs here,
I am completely new to web-developing and trying to build my website.
Here the problem with the CSS code is that the middle navbar items (`.nav_links li`) doesn't stay at one line as it pushes the Trends item in navbar to start at a newline as seen in the attached image in the post(Please see the attached image). I want all items to stay at one line with the same spacing between the items.
Maybe the fix is simple, I'd really appreciate your help, thanks

[image]

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>N Dress Boutique. Now Shop Everything at your Finger Tips</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h4 class="logo">N</h4>
            <nav class='nav1'>
                <ul class='nav_links'>
                    <a><li href="#home">Home</li></a>
                    <a><li href="#dresses">Dresses</li></a>
                    <a><li href="#trends">Trends</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a href="#"><button class="button">Contact</button></a>
        </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color:#b7b7b7;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 10%;
    background-color: #332323;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-size:large;
}

.nav_links li  {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    
}

.button {
    background-color: #302b2b;
    padding: 5px 10%;
    color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only give each item a width of 40%. If you want them all to stay on the same line, you should change it to 33% or 30%.

Comment: That changes the spacing between the items and items overlap on each other. However, changing width to 70px fixes the problem.

Comment: Should I keep width 70px? If it's good coding or implementation, I am fine with it or there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to solve this is using a table instead. It makes your items always fit in the same row. Note that the table must be small enough otherwise it is going to overflow from the screen.

Comment: I haven't tried it. Most of the youtube tutorials I have seen is they are always using nav tags

Comment: Let me play with your idea and I will get around with it.